# if satatement in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that by using a `groupby` function I divide them.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("/content/project.xlsx")
common = df.groupby("col_3")
split = dict(iter(common))
list1 = []
for i, g in df.groupby('col_3'):
  list1.append(i)
```

Now I want with using for loop apply some changes on the dataframes that I extract like b:

```
for m in list1:
  df3= split[m]
  if df3.loc[df3.col_8== 1]:
    df1 = df3.drop(["col_11"], axis=1)
  else:
    df2= df3[["col_8","col_9","col_10","col_11"]]
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Why is that?

This is my dataframe:

[image]

Comment: could you show an example of the dataframe you have?

Comment: i added the pic of dataframe

Comment: `col_8` has many values, it does not equal just one value (1 is what you are testing for). That should be why you a  get a `ValueError`

Comment: i know that the col_8 has [1,2,3] i want if value [1] drop col_11 and if value is [2,3] select ["col_8","col_9","col_10","col_11"]

Comment: What line are you receiving the error? That can help figure out what's going on.

Comment: in this line i got receiving error : if df3.loc[df3.col_8== 1]:

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df3[df3['col_8'] == 1]
df1.drop(['col_11'], inplace=True, axis=1)

df2 = df3[df3['col_8'] != 1]
df2 = df2[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10', 'col_11']].copy()
```

No for loop needed just filter. First off, .loc[this needs to be an integer val for index]. You are also comparing a single value to an entire column. When you say something like df3.col8 you are referring to an entire column so you couldn't compare it to a single int such as 1.

Ouputs:

```
  col2  col_3   col_4  col_8  col_9    col_10
0    a    123   89562      1     85      jack
3    v    252    5459      1      8      rose
5    z    698  988592      1   5787  jennifer
6    b    654   56562      1   5665    androw

   col_8  col_9  col_10 col_11
1      2     22    bill      t
2      3     22  amanda      f
4      2   5652   marry      f
7      2    564   james      t
8      3    654    sara      f
```

Comment: you can see i put all the value of col_8 in list1: [123, 252, 654, 698] i used for loop to create dataframe based on value of list1. for instance df3 = split[123] i got this dataframe that have 123 in the col_8

Comment: Can you create the df you posted through the for loop - the if statements?

Comment: To my understanding this is the output you are looking for above ^^ let me know if that assumption is wrong.

Comment: it is not the exact output that i want but your answer clear some parts for me thanks.